# What is the Tacoma Narrows bridge doing in this picture?

Tags: single-word-requests, image-identification

When the plate of the bridge assumes the unnatural shape showed in the following picture, what is this phenomenon called? **Contortion** (example: *the bridge was contorting ...*). I'm not so sure, as I think *contortion* normally refers to the (unnatural) shape of human/animal body. Is there a better word?

[image: Photo of bridge]

Comment: In case anyone's interested  - the bridge shown is the Tacoma Narrows Bridge - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacoma_Narrows_Bridge_(1940)

Comment: What aspect of the phenomenon are you looking for a word to describe - the motion of the bridge? the static shape as frozen in the picture? the physical process that caused the motion?

Comment: All the word suggestions below are great answers, and are all words that describe it adequately, but I've actually heard the sentence "He pulled a Tacoma Narrows," in reference to someone twisting wildly as they fell down. It seems to be a very unique thing.

Comment: The phenomenon is caused by resonance.

Comment: If you've never seen the footage of the bridge (nicknamed 'Galloping Gertie') swaying and undulating, see [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j-zczJXSxnw). It's impressive.

Comment: Who is the audience? If it is engineers, I would use the terms professionals use.

Comment: There's a **lot** of words for this behavior, because it resembles a lot of other naturally experienced phenomena, some of which are manifested by -- or imitated by -- humans, and which therefore are important and memorialized in human language.

Comment: It could be worth noting in the question that the bridge is *in motion*. It's not fixed in the position shown in the photo, which makes words like 'contorted' (which refer to a specific position) less relevant.

Comment: I know this is (very slightly) off topic, but isn't the answer to the title question related to the fact that the photographer decided it was a worthy subject to be photographed?

Comment: I thought you were going to award 50 points to an answer that deserved special recognition?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This bridge is ***thrashing*** or maybe even ***convulsing***.

I'm adding to this question at this late date because I think the answers to date have been overly restricted to technical (i.e., 'scientific') answers.  When someone keels over clutching their chest, one is much likelier to hear "Oh my god, she's having a heart attack!" instead of the more medical "Oh my god, she's having a myocardial infarction!"

Comment: Why did you choose *thrashing* and *convulsing*? Could you provide any references which suggest they are suitable terms?

Comment: @Mari-LouA I'm using these words in their standard dictionary definition.  Thrashing seems appropriate given the 'tosses' that this bridge gave to cars as they drove over it, which is visible in some videos.  Also see edit.

Comment: Following your edit, I'd say that one is more likelier to hear or use (excluding *oscillation*, which is hardly jargonesque) the bridge: bended, twisted, swayed, "tossed and turned" (as a metaphor) and undulated than *thrashed* or *convulsing*.

Comment: I agree, to me thrashing and convulsing connote non-rhythmic movement, which doesn't match the behavior of the bridge.

Answer (score 29):

While contortion may sometimes refer to the shape of a human/animal body, it does not necessarily.

[Contortion](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/contortion) and [torsion](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/torsion) both refer to the twisting (unnatural in the case of contortion) of an **object**, which certainly seems relevant for the photo you provided.

The phenomenon in question actually deals with the [resonance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resonance) of the bridge, and is not really a "twisting" motion as contortion implies, but is actually an [oscillation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oscillate) due to resonant frequencies of the object. (Though it certainly appears as a twisting motion when driven to that type of extreme.)

As pointed out by others and in comments, [aeroelastic flutter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aeroelasticity) played the major roll and not resonance. Though it remains an example of resonance, calling it resonance oversimplifies what actually occurred and it would be more accurate to state that it was aeroelastic flutter combined with resonance.[(source1)](http://www.newton.dep.anl.gov/askasci/phy05/phy05494.htm)[(source2)](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1986STIN...8631989L)[(source3)](http://aviation.cours-de-math.eu/ATPL-081-POF/flutter.php)[(source4)](http://courses.washington.edu/cee517/scanlanTN.pdf)

Comment: 'tortuous' is the technical medical term for a vessel that has more bends in it than usual.

Comment: Although the Tacoma narrows is always shown as a classic example of resonance - it wasn't. The movement was caused by flutter, it didn't have to be at a resonance.

Comment: @mgb Edited to reflect the roll of flutter, though resonance still played its part (the best explanation is actually a combination of the two).

Answer (score 28):

There are different technical words to refer to the motion of a suspended bridge. **Oscillation** is the most widely used term.

For a potentially destructive oscillation, you could use **flutter**; this is a [technical term](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aeroelasticity#Flutter).

Comment: Oscillation is the result of the resonant response to wind blowing over the bridge.

Comment: @CanisLupus While the bridge was oscillating, note that the collapse of the bridge was not due to resonance, as is commonly believed.

Answer (score 19):

I don't think it would be such a bad thing to fall back to a simpler word: **twisted**. In this case, if you were to say "in high winds, the bridge surface twisted" (or "the bridge became twisted"), I think that adequately (and clearly) communicates what we see in that photo.

I'm all about using the best word for the situation-- and in this case, to communicate that concept, I think "twisted" is optimal.

Comment: I would use twisted if you are writing a general piece. Trying to sound better by using technical terms is confusing if you don't use them in their exact technical meaning.

Answer (score 17):

I'd say *buckled*, which fits the Dictionary.com definition: "3. to bend, warp, bulge, or collapse: The bridge buckled in the storm."

There may be a technical engineering term, but I suspect most people would grasp *buckled* more readily.

Comment: "Collapse" is the version "buckled" that immediately pops into mind for me - it's not a good choice if you want others to easily distinguish the collapsing vs non-collapsing type of "buckling".

Comment: Buckled actually implies something short of collapsed to me.  I get the picture of something with a major structural problem but that is still standing.  There is room for interpretation, I agree.

Comment: Of course, this bridge actually did collapse.

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail: My thoughts excactly when I was reading the definition in this answer.

Comment: buckling has a specific technical meaning, when a member fails under compression by folding - like a crushed drink can. If you are describing the failure of a bridge I would avoid it

Answer (score 15):

The phenomenon that cause this movement is called ***"Resonance"***. The wind at a specific speed cause a ***Oscillation*** on the bridge that is equal the ***"Natural Frequency"*** of the structure.

> The catastrophic vibrations that destroyed the bridge were not due to simple mechanical **resonance**, but to a more complicated interaction between the bridge and the winds passing through it — a phenomenon known as aeroelastic flutter.

Source: [Resonance Failure of the original Tacoma Narrows Bridge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resonance#Failure_of_the_original_Tacoma_Narrows_Bridge)

Comment: ["In many physics textbooks, the event is presented as an example of elementary forced resonance with the wind providing an external periodic frequency that matched the natural structural frequency, though its actual cause of failure was aeroelastic flutter. Its failure also boosted research in the field of bridge aerodynamics-aeroelastics, the study of which has influenced the designs of all the world's great long-span bridges built since 1940."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galloping_Gertie) 
Actually, it is wrong to say that the phenomenon that causes the movement is resonance.

Comment: This vibration was caused by aeroelastic fluttering. The wind speed measured that day was being fairly constant, there was no forced resonance.

Comment: @ArchJ Aeroelastic fluttering and resonance oscillation go hand in hand usually. They aren't normally disjoint occurrences.

Comment: When the oscillation matches to the natural frequency it intensifies the amplitude of the oscillation. Wikipedia:"In physics, resonance is the tendency of a system to oscillate at a greater amplitude at some frequencies than at others. At these frequencies, even small periodic driving forces can produce large amplitude oscillations, because the system stores vibrational energy." With out the resonance the wind can produce this movement, but the bridge will offer a great resistence and turn back to original shape.

Answer (score 15):

The first word that came to my mind was **undulate**.

> undulating 
>   present participle of un·du·late (Verb)
>   1. Move with a smooth wavelike motion: "her body undulated to the thumping rhythm of the music".
>   2. Have a wavy form or outline: "delightful views over undulating countryside".

Comment: I think undulate is the right word for this, especially if you have seen the video. For me, undulation best captures the slow, back and forth oscillation of the bridge.

Answer (score 5):

You are correct that "[contortion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contortion)" is often used in reference to human bodies. A preferable alternative might be "[contorted](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/contorted)", which has no such connotations and can be used appropriately with reference to a physical object.

UPDATE: As NominSim points out [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contorted) disagrees with the distinction I suggested here. Nevertheless, I maintain that in common usage, "contortion" is often associated with "contortionists" - a human activity. Wikipedia's redirect notwhithstanding, contorted does not have the same association. Perhaps this is just a matter of my own opinion, however.

Comment: Your wikipedia link is a redirect from contorted, seems unjustifiable to suggest a word that links directly to the word in question.

Comment: Contortion is a noun, contorted is an adjective, and both are derived from the same verb stem of "contort."  They are essentially the same word in this case.

Comment: @fluffy: watch out for the etymological fallacy. Just because two forms have the same root, does not mean they have the same meaning, or range of usage, or connotations.

Comment: @LarsH I agree, however in this case fluffy is correct, they have the same meaning. In fact contortion defaults to contorted in many online dictionarys.

Comment: @NominSim: I would agree with kmote that the two words have somewhat different (though overlapping) connotations (associations). Most dictionaries are usually far from complete when it comes to that level of nuance.

Answer (score 5):

My pick would be **warp**. For example, 'the bridge's warping became so extreme that it started to shake itself apart.'

Comment: Warping is generally a gradual and permanent deformation (e.g. of a board under long-term load) rather than sudden changes like this.

Answer (score 3):

This phenomenon is called ***resonating***. Example: *The bridge was resonating until the forces induced were greater than the force it could withstand, and it collapsed.*

Resonance, incidentally, implies that the amplitude of oscillation will increase until either the dampening forces prevent further increase or until the forces become too great for the structure to withstand.

Or, if you're looking for the specific shape, I'd use ***twisting*** or ***torsioning***.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't clear from your question whether you are looking for a simple description of the state of the bridge or a more technical answer. My feelings are that the words 'distortion' or 'distorted' are the most appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

I would go with *[bucked](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bucked)*:

> v. bucked, buck·ing, bucks v.intr.
>   1. To leap upward arching the back: The horse bucked in fright.
>   2. To charge with the head lowered; butt.
>   3. **To make sudden jerky movements**; jolt: The motor bucked and lurched before it finally ran smoothly.
>   4. To resist stubbornly and obstinately; balk.
>   5. Informal To strive with determination: bucking for a promotion.

It works both with the literal meaning (definition 3) and as metaphor (definition 1):  *The bridged bucked in the wind.*

If the motion in question is gentler, *sway* seems like a good choice.

Comment: It doesn't seem like all that sudden to me. *Buckled* is better.

Comment: Are you suggesting that 'bucked' be used as an adjective? or are you just giving the verb as in 'The bridge is bucking' ?

Comment: @Mitch The usage here is as an intransitive verb.

Answer (score 2):

From a mechanical engineer's perspective, it is correct to say that the bridge is **contorting**.

I would comment on some of the previous posts, but I am new to this forum.

Although not specifically asked for, many others are identifying the cause of this torsion as **resonance**; however, this is not technically correct. As Shyam points out, the bridge failed due to a phenomenon called **aeroelastic flutter**.

Resonance is a technical term which implies that a periodic force was applied at the same frequency of the structure's natural frequency. The wind blowing on the Tacoma Narrows Bridge was not periodic in nature: it was a constant breeze. Thus, resonance is not technically correct here.

Comment: isn't contorting usually (only?) a transitive verb?

Comment: @Merk, not sure about *usually*, but Merriam-Webster gives a definition for and examples of both transitive and intransitive uses: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/contort

Answer (score 2):

I would say "twisted". This deformation reminds every mathematician of how you form a Möbius band, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_strip for pictures and details. The way you do that is to take a strip of paper, twist one end around 180 degrees, and then glue the ends together. Of course, with the bridge nothing is glued, but the movement is similar. By the way, a film of this bridge breaking down is very popular for use in applied mathematics courses when the topic is resonance.

Answer (score 1):

The bridge was **whipsawed** by the wind.
To whipsaw: To cause to move or alternate rapidly in contrasting directions
[Whipsaw](http://www.yourdictionary.com/whipsaw)